# How to switch window on HtmlUnit

Tags: java, windows, selenium, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I have a selenium code below which switch window to another window. How do I do the same thing with HtmlUnit not HtmlUnitDriver.

```
Set windows = driver.getWindowHandles();  List windowsH = new ArrayList<>(windows); driver.switchTo().window(windowsH.get(1));
```

Can someone give me a sample code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on HtmlUnit (2.56.0) api docs:

```
WebClient webClient = ...
List<WebWindow> windows = webClient.getWebWindows();
webClient.setCurrentWindow(windows.get(1));
```

---

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.56.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**Reference**

https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/apidocs/index.html

https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#getWebWindows--

https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setCurrentWindow-com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindow-